# Catch Click Event on UP icon for SearchView in Android.

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-search

I have implemented **`SearchView`** on my **`ListView`**. When i enter some text in **`EditText`** of this search widget, it filters the contents in my list. But if i close this search widget on clicking **`UP/home`** icon without clearing the text in **`EditText`**, i am  still having the filtered list not the complete list.

So i need to catch the event of **`UP`** icon for **`SearchView`** to clear the text in **`EditText`**, or is there some other way for that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be, you need to try this one instead of relying on **`UP`** icon click event.

```
menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)
            {
                // Do something when collapsed

                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)
            {
                // Do something when Expanded
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do we also have overflow icon click listener?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do that.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    // this is item ID of that back part which you want
    case android.R.id.home:
          // Control will come here when back/or app icon is pressed
    break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Sory, but it doesn't work. I have debugged and control does not even come in `onOptionItemSelected`. May be, the **`UP`** icon associated with this `SearchView` is not as same as the used for UP navigation.

Comment: Thnx @Techfist, found a sound solution.